# RxAndroid: Fetch data from multiple apis

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-android

I have a usecase where I get list of userids from 1 Api as a Single<List> and I need to fetch all the users from a different Api which returns Single.

```
fun fetchUserIds(): Single<List<String>>

fun fetchUser(id: String): Single<User>
```

I need to return a List eventually. What is the ideal way to do this using RxJava?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Flowable` to iterate over the userIds and call the `fetchUser` on each element. Then you can combine the result (e.g `toList` or `collect`):

```java
fetchUserIds()
  .flatMap(ids -> Flowable.fromIterable(ids).flatMapSingle(this::fetchUser).toList())
  .subscribe(users -> {
      //list of users
   });
```